# cant load osm2pgsql, crush in configurate command

Tags: c++, openstreetmap, nominatim

when i try run configurate command from Nominatim, i get error:

```
libtool: link: g++ -g -O2 -o osm2pgsql osm2pgsql.o -pthread  ./.libs

/libosm2pgsql.a -L/usr/lib -L/opt/bitnami/postgresql/lib -lpq -L/opt/bitnami/common/lib -lxml2 -lz -liconv -lbz2 -L/bitnami/lampstackDev-linux-x64/output/postgresql/lib -lgeos /usr/lib/libproj.so -lprotobuf-c -L/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu -llua5.2 -lm -ldl -lboost_filesystem -lboost_system -lboost_thread -pthread
./.libs/libosm2pgsql.a(geometry-builder.o): In function `coords2nodes':
/home/azureuser/Nominatim-2.4.0/osm2pgsql/geometry-builder.cpp:72: undefined reference to `geos::geom::Coordinate::~Coordinate()'
/home/azureuser/Nominatim-2.4.0/osm2pgsql/geometry-builder.cpp:72: undefined reference to `geos::geom::Coordinate::~Coordinate()'
./.libs/libosm2pgsql.a(geometry-builder.o): In function `geometry_builder::get_wkt_simple(osmNode const*, int, int) const':
/home/azureuser/Nominatim-2.4.0/osm2pgsql/geometry-builder.cpp:107: undefined reference to `geos::geom::Coordinate::~Coordinate()'
/home/azureuser/Nominatim-2.4.0/osm2pgsql/geometry-builder.cpp:107: undefined reference to `geos::geom::Coordinate::~Coordinate()'
./.libs/libosm2pgsql.a(geometry-builder.o): In function `geometry_builder::get_wkt_split(osmNode const*, int, int, double) const':
/home/azureuser/Nominatim-2.4.0/osm2pgsql/geometry-builder.cpp:165: undefined reference to `geos::geom::Coordinate::~Coordinate()'
./.libs/libosm2pgsql.a(geometry-builder.o):/home/azureuser/Nominatim-2.4.0/osm2pgsql/geometry-builder.cpp:221: more undefined references to `geos::geom::Coordinate::~Coordinate()' follow
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[2]: *** [osm2pgsql] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/azureuser/Nominatim-2.4.0/osm2pgsql'
make[1]: *** [all] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/azureuser/Nominatim-2.4.0/osm2pgsql'
make: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
bitnami@vrosm:~/Nominatim-2.4.0$
```

how i can fix this problem?

Comment: Is this really the first error when running `./configure`?

Comment: Have you installed libgeos-dev ?